# get [Today] working

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In Share Point 2010, I have a list of library books that are checked out. This list has a due date field.

This is what I want:
When the books are past due a certain number of days from today's date, I want those items to be highlighted in red.

This is what I have tried. Created a calculated field, that calculates number of days from today's date till due date
and shows as an integer. This calculated field only works if the list is updated. Meaning, if tomorrow I look at the list
the calculated field does not reflect the calculation, unless I edit any item and save it.

My question is what mechanism should I use to have this calculated field updated everyday, with out any intervention.

Answer (score 2):

The short of it is, this isn't possible. Calculated columns only recalculate when the item is modified. You need a timer job like Aanchal suggests, I have seen people trying javascript hacks to get it to work.

Christophe [poses an alternative solution](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/) that might work for you. He also has alternate solutions at the bottom of the mentioned article.

```
=[Due Date]-ROUNDDOWN([Modified],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom timer job that will monitor your sharepoint library items. You can write your whole custom logic there and also you can update the listitem .In this way no intervention will be required.